# "#{loginBean.nom}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'loginBean' resolved to null

Tags: jsf

I try every solution but still have this problem:

> /Acceuil.xhtml @19,30 value="#{loginBean.nom}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'loginBean' resolved to null

I use `tomcat 7` as server.

Can you help me to find the problem?

Comment: Where's your bean code?

Answer (score -1):

i use two bean

this is LoginBean:

```
package tn.gestiondintervention.beans;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import tn.gestiondintervention.model.Login;
import tn.gestiondintervention.service.LoginService;
import tn.gestiondintervention.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl;

@ManagedBean(name = "loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean {

    private List<Login> loginList;
    private String nom;
    private String matricule;


    public List<Login> getLoginList() {
        loginList=new ArrayList<Login>();
        LoginService loginService= new LoginServiceImpl();
        loginList=loginService.listLogin();
        return loginList;
    }
    public void setLoginList(List<Login> loginList) {
        this.loginList = loginList;
    }
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    public String getMatricule() {
        return matricule;
    }
    public void setMatricule(String matricule) {
        this.matricule = matricule;
    }
    public String authentification()
    {
        LoginService loginService= new LoginServiceImpl();
        Login login=loginService.getLogin(getMatricule());
        if (login == null) {
            return "erroracceuil";
        } else {
            if (login.getNom() == "admin")

            {
                return "succesadmin";
            } else
                return "succes";
        }

}
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public String inscription()
    {
        LoginService loginService= new LoginServiceImpl();
        Login login = loginService.getLogin(getMatricule());

        if (login == null){


            login.setNom(getNom());
            login.setMatricule(getMatricule());
            loginService.addLogin(login);

            return "inscript";
        }
        else return "errorinscript";
    }
    public String listUser(){

        return "succeslisteutilisateur";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this apply? http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/blog/2010/03/05/jee-cdi-tip-target-unreachable-identifier-resolved-to-null/

Comment: thank u for your help i use faces-config under web-inf ,

Comment: how can i replace it with beans Xml

Comment: faces-config is right, you need an additional beans.xml file with the contents in the link.

Comment: is there any change in the LoginBean (deleting managedbean for example